# Programmatically invoking a button with CKEditor 4

Tags: ckeditor, integration-testing

Hello CKEditor experts,

Can I use a javascript-code (in-page) to invoke a button and dialog of the CKEditor?

I am trying to bring back the usage of the "anchor" button into our CryptPad collaborative suite. To do so, I wish to write an integration test that invokes the "anchor" button then check that the exported content indeed includes the expected `<a name="...">` element. Our tests are actually scripts running inside the page (and invoked by selenium). What function could I invoke, as part of the JS page, to invoke that button or invoke exactly the same content addition as the invocation of the button does?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually buttons, have defined commands. If you don't know what command is bound to button you want to invoke, then you can find it:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.insances[ instanceName ];
console.log( editor.ui.get( 'Anchor' ).command ) // 'anchor'
editor.execCommand( 'anchor' ) // Dialog opens
```

Once we know our command, testing code would like like:

```
editor.on( 'dialogShow', function( evt ) {
  evt.data // Dialog instance
  // All code goes here
} );

editor.execCommand( 'anchor' );
```

Visit docs for more detailed informations on dialog methods, which might help you with proper testing.
https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dialog.html

Comment: Thank you @kajeta-w-li, this has worked wonderfully and has allowed me to [invoke the anchor menu](https://github.com/xwiki-labs/cryptpad/commit/0dc1500784051226a6bf464b08035ade66958a8d#diff-4b732d84f3b56628c7d6b798903b759aR780) [then to input into the dialog](https://github.com/xwiki-labs/cryptpad/commit/0dc1500784051226a6bf464b08035ade66958a8d#diff-4b732d84f3b56628c7d6b798903b759aR771).